# Problem in Export csv file in php

Tags: php

I need to export csv file in php using mysql query .But when i export filename like this "yourfilename.csv_".

My code is

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");

header("Content-Disposition: \"inline; filename=yourfilename.csv\"");  

$query = "SELECT * FROM login";

$result = mysql_query($query) ;

echo "username ,password \r\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "$row[user],$row[pass]\r\n";  
}
```

I need file name "yourfilename.csv".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have MySql return a query result to file directly with

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM my_table;
```

and then just do ([also see Example #1 Download dialog)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.csv"');
readfile('result.csv');
```