# Unable to export CSV file in PHP (data logged to console though)

Tags: php, csv, download

On clicking of a button in html file, I trigger this. All the rows' data is coming in $products. I want to directly download a CSV file by user's browser (no storing of a file on server). I have taken this code from another file of the company, where it's working perfectly. Here it refuses to work. This is the backend code:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "importData") {

    $where = " WHERE 1 ";
    if(isset($_POST['category_name']) && $_POST['category_name'] != ""){
        $where .= " AND ic.category_name = '" . $_POST['category_name'] . "'";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['sku']) && $_POST['sku'] != ""){
        $where .= " AND ic.sku = '" . $_POST['sku'] . "'";
    }

    $products = tep_db_fetchAll("SELECT p.sku, p.created_at, ic.category_name
        FROM ".TBL_PRODUCT. " p 
        JOIN ".TBL_IMPORT_CATEGORIES." ic ON p.import_category_id = ic.id
        $where ");

    $filename = 'import_categories_data'.time().'.csv';

    // Offer the CSV file for download (optional)
    header("Content-Type:application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=import_categories_data".time().".csv");

    $file = fopen("php://output", 'w'); // 'w' means opening the file for writing
    $headings = ["Sr#", "SKU", "Category", "CreatedDate"];
    fputcsv($file,$headings);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $data = [
            "Sr#" => $i++,
            "SKU" => $product['sku'],
            "Category" => $product['category_name'] ,
            "CreatedDate" => date("m/d/Y", strtotime($product['created_at'])),
        ];
        fputcsv($file, $data);
    }

    fclose($file);
    exit();
}
```

This is what I get in my Network Tab:
[image: Network tab results]

I tried changing 2nd header line as "filename='".$filename."'", essentially wrapping filename in quotes. Also confirmed that column names have no spaces in between them (not an issue I know). Still not working.

I also checked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513990/problem-in-export-csv-file-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com) but that's showing another way of resolving the issue. I want to know why the solution I've posted works on 1 webpage, but doesn't on another.

Also used ChatGPT for 1 hour but all solutions are failing.

P.S. Please Ignore the Import label. I know I'm exporting but kept it that way for a reason temporarily.

Comment: what is the issue you are getting, can you please paste a screenshot of it

Comment: File is not downloading at all that's the issue. No error message is coming. I'm getting the response I posted in Networks Tab. I want browser to download a file. @Satya

Comment: can you put these headers as well header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");   before rest of your headers and see

Comment: @Satya sorry but that is all nonsense. A response can only have one header of each type. Your commands will simply overwrite each other's values 
leaving only the last one, which sets a completely fake content type. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616753/5947043 instead of relying on cargo-cult code which you clearly haven't taken the time to understand properly before pasting it

Comment: @AbdullahAhmad are you using regular postback to trigger the download request, or ajax?

Comment: @Adyson im using ajax

Comment: Ok. Well AJAX doesn't download files. The data from the response just goes into the variable in the AJAX request's callback. That's how AJAX works. You _can_ make the browser then prompt for a download though, [with a bit of extra work](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+file+via+ajax)